# Print PDF file silently in Asp.net MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, browser, web-applications, printing

I want to print PDF file silently without any print preview. Currently I used `return File(stream, fileName, "application/pdf")` from an MVC action for print but it will download file.

It is possible to send PDF file direct to printer without print preview ?

Comment: Short answer is no. Your server cannot control the client.

Comment: Is there any other solution for this? @StephenMuecke

Comment: No. Its up to the user to print it. And you don't even know what printers are on the client.

Answer (score 0):

you can't unless If you know the users who needs silent print or your app is internal in company then you can create custom protocol to communicate with users pc.

protocol runs an app which sends file to the default printer. once users select check box not to see warning again. they will be able to send files to their default printer directly. Just like skype. if you type skype:212312 on your browser then skype application will run and call given number.

the app that is called by protocol is up to you. You can either create a custom app or you use 3rd party applications.

[image: you can see dialog box below]

Answer (score 0):

No. Across the web, downloads and system operations will always require user interactions to confirm things.

A solution might be to create a desktop application or service that communicates with your web application, this app/service would then download and print outside the context of the web application and you will have much more control.